# Python Win32Pipe not being able to find file for Pipe

Tags: python, windows, bluetooth, pipe, python-multiprocessing

This is the error I am getting

```
pipe = win32file.CreateFile(pipe_name, win32file.GENERIC_WRITE, 0, None, win32file.OPEN_EXISTING, 0, None)
pywintypes.error: (2, 'CreateFile', 'The system cannot find the file specified.')
```

For context, I have 3 files in one python project. First is main.py which is used to create the Pipe and then use the multiproccessing module to run the other 2 files. One is called server.py which is the writer for the pipe. The other is gui.py which is the reader.

Here is the code

main.py

```
import multiprocessing
import os
import win32file
import win32pipe


def run_original_program():
    os.system("server.py")

def run_gui_application():
    os.system("gui.py")

def create_pipe(pipe_name):
    try:
        # Create a named pipe
        pipe = win32pipe.CreateNamedPipe(
            pipe_name,
            win32pipe.PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,
            win32pipe.PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE | win32pipe.PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE | win32pipe.PIPE_WAIT,
            1, 65536, 65536,
            300,
            None
        )
        print(f"Named pipe '{pipe_name}' created.")
        return pipe
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error:", e)
        return None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pipe_name = r'\\.\pipe\my_pipe'
    create_pipe(pipe_name)


    original_program_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=run_original_program)
    gui_application_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=run_gui_application)

    original_program_process.start()
    gui_application_process.start()

    original_program_process.join()
    gui_application_process.join()
```

gui.py

```
import tkinter as tk
from threading import Thread
import time
import win32file
import win32pipe


def reader(pipe):
    try:
        data_received, _ = win32file.ReadFile(pipe, 4096)
        print("Data received by reader:", data_received.decode())
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error:", e)


class MessageApp:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Real-Time Message Display")

        self.message_label = tk.Label(root, text="", font=("Helvetica", 14))
        self.message_label.pack(pady=20)

        # Connect to the named pipe when initializing the app
        pipe_name = r'\\.\pipe\my_pipe'
        time.sleep(100000)
        self.pipe = win32file.CreateFile(pipe_name, win32file.GENERIC_READ, 0, None, win32file.OPEN_EXISTING, 0, None)
        win32pipe.ConnectNamedPipe(self.pipe, None)

        # Start a separate thread to simulate receiving messages
        self.message_thread = Thread(target=self.receive_messages)
        self.message_thread.daemon = True
        self.message_thread.start()

    def receive_messages(self):
        while True:
            # Simulate receiving a message (replace this with your actual message-receiving logic)
            received_message = "New message at " + time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")

            # Update the GUI with the received message
            self.root.after(0, self.update_message, received_message)

            # Simulate variable message arrival times
            time.sleep(2)

    def update_message(self, new_message):
        self.message_label.config(text=new_message)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = MessageApp(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

server.py

```
import bluetooth
import win32file

# Initial Setup for blue tooth, creating socket and binding to bluetooth adapter
server_socket = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)
server_socket.bind(("8c:c6:81:9a:63:a1", bluetooth.PORT_ANY))
server_socket.listen(1)

# UUID is just an identifier for bluetooth connection. Still not exactly sure how it works
uuid = "00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"  # SPP
# not exactly sure but I think this is what the client will see when it is configured to search for server
# rather than directly connecting
bluetooth.advertise_service(server_socket, "SampleServerL2CAP", service_id=uuid, service_classes=[uuid])

def writer(pipe, data_to_send):
    try:
        win32file.WriteFile(pipe, data_to_send.encode())
        print("Data sent to reader:", data_to_send)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error:", e)



while True:

    # Open the pipe for writing
    pipe_name = r'\\.\pipe\my_pipe'
    data_to_send = "Hello from the writer process!"
    pipe = win32file.CreateFile(pipe_name, win32file.GENERIC_WRITE, 0, None, win32file.OPEN_EXISTING, 0, None)
    writer(pipe, data_to_send)


    print("Waiting for incoming connection...")
    client_socket, address = server_socket.accept()
    print("Accepted connection from", str(address))

    print("Waiting for data...")
    total = 0
    while True:
        try:
            data = client_socket.recv(1024)
        except bluetooth.BluetoothError as e:
            break
        if not data:
            break
        total += len(data)
        print("Total byte read:", total)


    client_socket.close()
    print("Connection closed")

server_sock.close()
```

I am pretty new to both pipes and bluetoot connection but I am hoping I am at least on the right track

I tried checking the pipe_name to make sure it is consistent throughout the programs. I also tried adding in a timer to give some time for the pipe to be created before reading.